# Javascript for loop causes error - maybe technique wrong?

Tags: javascript

For introduction: https://mytechservinginternetmeals.blogspot.com/2021/10/how-to-start-making-browser-video-game.html

Could anyone tell how to fix the error in code that try's to check errors in it?

THIS CAUSES TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'resourcePath')

```
const novietojumi = [
  "0.1221 0.1221",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
];
let arrayLength = novietojumi.length;

console.log(arrayLength);

for (let i = 0, x = 0, y = 0; i < arrayLength; i++, y++, x++) {
  //console.log(novietojumi[i]);

  const NOV = novietojumi[i].split(" ");
  console.log(NOV);
  console.log("KOORD1", NOV[0]);
  console.log("KOORD2", NOV[1]);
   _P.set(NOV[x], 0.0, NOV[x]);
  _P.add(center);
  _P.multiplyScalar(50.0);

  const key = '__scenery__[' + _P.x + '][' + _P.z + ']';
  if (this.FindEntity(key)) {
    //continue;
  }

  _V.copy(_P);

  _P.x += (this.noise_.Get(_P.x, 0.0, _P.z) * 2.0 - 1.0) * 25.0;
  _P.z += (this.noise_.Get(_P.x, 1.0, _P.z) * 2.0 - 1.0) * 25.0;
  _P.y = terrain.GetHeight(_P)[0];

  const biome = this.FindBiome_(terrain, _P);

  const roll = this.noise_.Get(_V.x, 2.0, _V.z);
  if (roll > _BIOMES[biome]) {
    //continue;
  }

  const e = this.SpawnAt_(biome, _P);

  //console.log(e);
  e.SetPosition(_P);

  //console.log(e, key);
  this.Manager.Add(e, key);

  e.SetActive(false);
  this.crap_.push(e);
}
```

THIS DOES NOT:

```
for (let x = -10; x <= 10; ++x) {
  for (let y = -10; y <= 10; ++y) {
    _P.set(x, 0.0, y);
    _P.add(center);
    _P.multiplyScalar(50.0);

    const key = '__scenery__[' + _P.x + '][' + _P.z + ']';
    if (this.FindEntity(key)) {
      continue;
    }

    _V.copy(_P);

    _P.x += (this.noise_.Get(_P.x, 0.0, _P.z) * 2.0 - 1.0) * 25.0;
    _P.z += (this.noise_.Get(_P.x, 1.0, _P.z) * 2.0 - 1.0) * 25.0;
    _P.y = terrain.GetHeight(_P)[0];

    const biome = this.FindBiome_(terrain, _P);

    const roll = this.noise_.Get(_V.x, 2.0, _V.z);
    if (roll > _BIOMES[biome]) {
      //continue;
    }

    const e = this.SpawnAt_(biome, _P);

    e.SetPosition(_P);

    this.Manager.Add(e, key);

    e.SetActive(false);
    this.crap_.push(e);
  }
}
```

THIS CODE sample is where error gets found :

```
const _SCENERY = {
  birch1: {
    base: 'Birch_1.fbx',
    resourcePath: './resources/trees/FBX/',
    names: {
      Bark: 'Birch_Bark.png',
      Leaves: 'Birch_Leaves_Yellow.png'
    },
    scale: 0.075,
    biomes: ['forest'],
    collision: true,
  },
  tree1: {
    base: 'Tree_1.fbx',
    resourcePath: './resources/trees/FBX/',
    names: {
      Bark: 'Tree_Bark.jpg',
      Leaves: 'Leaves_Blue.png'
    },
    scale: 0.1,
    biomes: ['forest'],
    collision: true,
  },
  rock1: {
    base: 'Rock_1.fbx',
    resourcePath: './resources/nature/FBX/',
    names: {},
    scale: 0.025,
    biomes: ['arid', 'desert'],
  },
  rockMoss1: {
    base: 'Rock_Moss_1.fbx',
    resourcePath: './resources/nature/FBX/',
    names: {},
    scale: 0.025,
    biomes: ['forest'],
  },
  plant1: {
    base: 'Plant_1.fbx',
    resourcePath: './resources/nature/FBX/',
    names: {},
    scale: 0.05,
    biomes: ['forest', 'arid'],
  },
  grass1: {
    base: 'Grass_1.fbx',
    resourcePath: './resources/nature/FBX/',
    names: {},
    scale: 0.05,
    biomes: ['forest', 'arid'],
  },
  flowers1: {
    base: 'Flowers.fbx',
    resourcePath: './resources/nature/FBX/',
    names: {},
    scale: 0.05,
    biomes: ['forest'],
  },
};

const _BIOMES = {
  desert: 0.1,
  forest: 0.8,
  arid: 0.6,
};

const multiples = {
  birch1: {
    name: 'Birch_',
    key: 'birch',
    num: 10
  },
  tree1: {
    name: 'Tree_',
    key: 'tree',
    num: 10
  },
  rock1: {
    name: 'Rock_',
    key: 'rock',
    num: 7
  },
  rockMoss1: {
    name: 'Rock_Moss_',
    key: 'rockMoss',
    num: 7
  },
  plant1: {
    name: 'Plant_',
    key: 'plant',
    num: 5
  },
  grass1: {
    name: 'Grass_',
    key: 'grass',
    num: 2
  },
};


SpawnAt_(biome, spawnPos) {
  const matchingScenery = [];
  for (let k in _SCENERY) {
    if (_SCENERY[k].biomes.indexOf(biome) >= 0) {
      matchingScenery.push(k);
    }
  }

  const roll = this.noise_.Get(spawnPos.x, 3.0, spawnPos.z);
  const randomProp = _SCENERY[
    matchingScenery[Math.round(roll * (matchingScenery.length - 1))]];

  const e = new entity.Entity();
  e.AddComponent(new render_component.RenderComponent({
    scene: this.params_.scene,
    resourcePath: randomProp.resourcePath,
    resourceName: randomProp.base,
    textures: {
      resourcePath: './resources/trees/Textures/',
      names: randomProp.names,
      wrap: true,
    },
    emissive: new THREE.Color(0x000000),
    specular: new THREE.Color(0x000000),
    scale: randomProp.scale * (0.8 + this.noise_.Get(spawnPos.x, 4.0, spawnPos.z) * 0.4),
    castShadow: true,
    receiveShadow: true,
    onMaterial: (m) => {
      if (m.name.search('Leaves') >= 0) {
        m.alphaTest = 0.5;
      }
    }
  }));

  if (randomProp.collision) {
    console.log("e");
    e.AddComponent(
      new spatial_grid_controller.SpatialGridController({
        grid: this.params_.grid
      }));
  }

  const q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), this.noise_.Get(spawnPos.x, 5.0, spawnPos.z) * 360);
  e.SetQuaternion(q);

  return e;
}
```

I am trying now -

```
  const center = new THREE.Vector3().copy(player.Position);

  center.x = Math.round(center.x / 50.0);
  center.y = 0.0;
  center.z = Math.round(center.z / 50.0);

  if (this.center_ && this.center_.equals(center)) {
    return;
  }

  this.center_ = center;

  const _P = new THREE.Vector3();
  const _V = new THREE.Vector3();
  const terrain = 
  this.FindEntity('terrain').GetComponent('TerrainChunkManager');


 const novietojumi = [
  "0.1221 0.1221",
  "0.1111 0.1111",
  ];
let arrayLength = novietojumi.length;

console.log(arrayLength);

for(let i = 0, x = 0, y = 0; i < arrayLength; i++, y++, x++) {


console.log(i);
    //console.log(novietojumi[i]);
    
const NOV = novietojumi[i].split(" ");
console.log(NOV, "NOV");
//console.log("KOORD1", NOV[0]);
//console.log("KOORD2", NOV[1]);


      _P.set(parseFloat(NOV[0], 0.0, parseFloat(NOV[1])));
      
      console.log(_P, "pozicijaaaa");
      _P.add(center);
      _P.multiplyScalar(50.0);

      console.log(_P, "22pozicijaaaa");

      const key = '__scenery__[' + _P.x + '][' + _P.z + ']';
      if (this.FindEntity(key)) {
        //continue;
      }

      _V.copy(_P);
      
      _P.x += (this.noise_.Get(_P.x, 0.0, _P.z) * 2.0 - 1.0) * 25.0;
      _P.z += (this.noise_.Get(_P.x, 1.0, _P.z) * 2.0 - 1.0) * 25.0;
      _P.y = terrain.GetHeight(_P)[0];

      const biome = this.FindBiome_(terrain, _P);
      
      console.log(biome, "BIOMA");
      
      
        console.log(_V.x, "VX");
      const roll = this.noise_.Get(_V.x, 2.0, _V.z);
      console.log(roll);
      if (roll > _BIOMES[biome]) {
        //continue;
      }

      const e = this.SpawnAt_(biome, _P);

      //console.log(e);
      e.SetPosition(_P);
      
      //console.log(e, key);



      this.Manager.Add(e, key);

      e.SetActive(false);
      this.crap_.push(e);
  }
```

for some reason for loop repeats more than array length of novietojumi array constant is telling it to..... that means, when player is walking around,this loop keeps spawning random elements...

Comment: The first code block never uses `resourcePath`. Which line is getting the error?

Comment: resourcePath: randomProp.resourcePath,

Comment: That's in the last code block, not the one you said has the error.

Comment: The problem is that `randomProp` is being set to `undefined`, presumably by `_SCENERY[matchingScenery[Math.round(roll * (matchingScenery.length - 1))]]`

Comment: randomProp is defined if I use the second code in article (with two for loops that does iteration for x and y) I guess....

Comment: what would cause first code snippet to fail that part?

Comment: I can't figure out what any of this code does. I suggest you step through it in the debugger, and check the value of `roll` when you get to that line.

Comment: somehow _V.x is undefined in first code sample, but I have no idea why....

Comment: I have no idea what `_P` and `_V` are. You're apparently using a library I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Those are vectors, which are both defined the same in both samples -       const _P = new THREE.Vector3();
      const _V = new THREE.Vector3();

Comment: I don't know what `this` is, I don't know what `FindBiome_` does, etc. I can't understand the code since there's so much missing context, and I'm not going to try.

Comment: In the first code block, `NOV[0]` and `NOV[1]` are strings. In the second block, `x` and `y` are numbers. I don't know if that difference matters to your vector class, but maybe that's the problem.

Comment: turns out, setting them to X (          _P.set(NOV[x], 0.0, NOV[x]);
) does not help at all , still _V.x is missing...

Answer (score 1):

`NOV[0]` and `NOV[1]` are strings, not numbers. Try:

```
_P.set(parseFloat(NOV[0], 0.0, parseFloat(NOV[1]));
```

Comment: Oh yeah, but I will need growing value, 0 1 then 2 3  and then 4 5 etc... thus need an X incrementation.

Comment: You're incrementing `i` and then using `const NOV = novietojumi[i].split(" ");`

Comment: _P.set(parseFloat(NOV[i], 0.0, parseFloat(NOV[i])));
 this causes same error...

Comment: Then I guess it's not because the values are strings.

Comment: You said that was the problem in a comment.

Comment: sorry too much coding, You were right...

Comment: well apparently I made it work but issue of collisions not getting detected is still there, check this stack question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395116/collisions-dont-get-detected-in-my-three-js-game-code